# How to resolve System Error 21359 on eBay's Trading API GET Requests?

Tags: ebay-api

I was testing several of eBay's Trading API GET requests (GetNotificationPreferences, GetNotificationsUsage, GetCategories, etc.) in Postman. About a week ago, everything was working fine. Couple days ago I went to make these calls again, and I keep receiving 21359 system errors (Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out).  The weird thing is, a POST request to SetNotificationPreferences works fine. Other non Trading APIs also work fine. I have been receiving this system error for the last 3 days, and I am not entirely sure what could be the issue. According to eBay, error 21359 "indicates an internal timeout has occured with the socket connection serving your request" and "the best course of action is to retry your request" which of course is not working for me. The error response can be seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetCategoriesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2023-10-29T09:58:54.900Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>21359</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
            <Value>Please try again.</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorClassification>SystemError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>1311</Version>
    <Build>E1311_CORE_APICATALOG_19146446_R1</Build>
</GetCategoriesResponse>
```

If there was an issue with the request, the response would indicate this. So is the issue with eBay or Postman or something else?

Let me know if more information is necessary and thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to pull unpaid orders and I've been getting the same issue:

2023-10-29T21:31:03.605ZFailureInput transfer has been terminated because your request timed out.Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out.21359ErrorPlease try again.SystemError1289E1289_CORE_APIXO_19220561_R1

I think it's on eBay's end. I'm not sure what changed though because the code I'm running I've been using daily for over a year now.

I've been in contact with their support team but they've been having issues recreating the error. I'll try to keep you updated if I learn more.

Comment: Awesome, thank you... I'll do the same. Thought it might be an issue with eBay, but if they cannot reproduce then maybe not. I created a post on eBay forums as well.

Comment: I changed the GET requests to POST requests and all calls work as expected... For example GetNotificationPreferences as POST request works.

Comment: That's odd. I just got it to work with the same. I wonder if they changed something in the documentation. Been running get requests for over a year now and no issues.